# Google Appengine - Entity class is not enhanced

Tags: google-app-engine

If I change an Entity class in a an appengine project in eclipse, in run time I get this error

Found Meta-Data for [classpath] but this class is not enhanced!! Please enhance the class before running DataNucleus.

Even when I undo the changes and re-run the local srv i get this error.

The only way around it is to get the old .class (using git).

I guess this is a way to prevent a class signature to change while the DB expect the old signature. is this true?

How can I get around it (for example when I want to ad fields to an entity)?

I found this in a thread:

> name explicitly all jdo-annotated classes in Project Settings ->
>   Google -> App Engine -> ORM under Eclipse.

It didn't work (or I misunderstood it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed:

> /war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar

and also from my build path - problem solved.

Comment: please close up the question.

Comment: what do you mean by that?